# Android NDK: Unsatisfied Link Error

Tags: android, android-ndk, vtk

This might be a silly question but I'm struggling with it. I've seen some post about it on SO but I still can't solve the error.

I am facing the kinda famous unsastified link error.

My code is as follow.

The native.cxx:

```
extern "C" {
    JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_VTKNative_JavaVTKLib_init(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj,  jint width, jint height);
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_VTKNative_JavaVTKLib_render(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jlong renWinP);
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_VTKNative_JavaVTKLib_onKeyEvent(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jlong udp,
      jboolean down, jint keyCode, jint metaState, jint repeatCount
      );
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_VTKNative_JavaVTKLib_onMotionEvent(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jlong udp,
      jint action,
      jint eventPointer,
      jint numPtrs,
      jfloatArray xPos, jfloatArray yPos,
      jintArray ids, jint metaState);
};


struct userData
{
  vtkRenderWindow *RenderWindow;
  vtkRenderer *Renderer;
  vtkAndroidRenderWindowInteractor *Interactor;
};

/*
 * Here is where you would setup your pipeline and other normal VTK logic
 */
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_VTKNativeJavaVTKLib_init(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj,  jint width, jint height)
{
    ....
}
```

And the error I get is:

```
06-30 00:02:50.468: E/AndroidRuntime(14916): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 960
06-30 00:02:50.468: E/AndroidRuntime(14916): Process: com.example.vtknative, PID: 14916
06-30 00:02:50.468: E/AndroidRuntime(14916): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.example.vtknative.JavaVTKLib.init:(II)J
06-30 00:02:50.468: E/AndroidRuntime(14916): at com.example.vtknative.JavaVTKLib.init(Native Method)
```

Hope it's not something crazy simple that I've just missed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rename your C++ function `Java_com_example_VTKNativeJavaVTKLib_init` to `Java_com_example_vtknative_JavaVTKLib_init` so it matches your Java declaration (com.example.vtknative.JavaVTKLib.init).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried that already and I still get the same error

Comment: Are you sure it was the same issue when you tried it ? you can use `nm` or `objdump` on the generated .so file to check if it indeed exposes the correct function name.

Comment: I've just tried again and it is the same issue. Yet nm doesn't give me any output

Comment: If nm doesn't show anything, maybe your source file isn't getting compiled !? what if you write some erroneous code inside it ? can you share your Android.mk or build.gradle files ?

Comment: Indeed you're right, I've tried to add some erroneous code and it does say that the build is just fine. Adding the Android.mk file in an EDIT :)

Comment: My bad it works just fine now! You were right, I just forgot to save changes made to my native code